# Permission to reload collection in Cloudera Search

Tags: solr, cloudera, solrcloud

I'm using CDH 5.11.1 (Solr 4.10.3) and have Kerberos authentication and Sentry authorization turned on for Solr.

I have created a collection and given a user all permissions to that collection as specified in https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-11-x/topics/search_sentry.html

> Access to each collection is governed by three privileges: Query, Update, and *. The wildcard (*) indicates all privileges.

This enables the user to query and add/delete documents in the collection, however it would be necessary to also give the user permission to change the schema of that collection. However, after updating the schema in Zookeeper it is necessary to call reload on the collection which the user is not able to do. ('User does not have privileges for admin').

Can I somehow give the user permission to reload the collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is necessary to also give the user UPDATE permission for admin collection.

See https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-11-x/topics/cdh_sg_sentry.html#concept_k4p_2fw_hw

(Although the documentation is nested under Sentry Policy File Authorization this also applies when using Sentry Service)